# How can I find the nearest AWS region to deploy an cloud application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an application which I need to deploy on the cloud, but I am not sure about my nearest AWS region, how can I find out my nearest AWS region based on my computer's location to do the deployment.

Thanks in advance
Umesh

Comment: Can you explain if you want that in python or terraform?

Comment: there's something convoluted I think would probably work which is to use a route 53 record which uses geolocation routing I think it's called. then grab the redirect url, from which you can know the closest region for deploy purposes.

Comment: simplest answer though, is to probably hard-code your region as that's generally what I do. for example you know you're based in CA then you you can use `us-west-1` as the default region.

Comment: Is this a python question or aws question?

Comment: @saedx1 i need ti in Python.

Comment: @rv.kvetch currently the application is hard-code, but i want to do the latency test before it suggest the deployment region.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

- You need to know the cities/states those regions are in.
- Get an estimation of their coordinates (longitude/latitude).
- Calculate the distance between you and all of them
- Choose the closest region.

```py
aws_regions = {
    "Virginia,US": ("us-east-1", (38.0339, -78.4860)),
    "Ohio,US": ("us-east-2", (40.4167, -82.9167)),
    "California,US": ("us-west-1", (37.7749, -122.4194)),
    "Oregon,US": ("us-west-2", (45.5200, -122.6819)),
    "Canada,CA": ("ca-central-1", (43.6532, -79.3832)),
    "Mumbai,IN": ("ap-south-1", (19.0760, 72.8777)),
    "Seoul,KR": ("ap-northeast-2", (37.5665, 126.9780)),
    "Singapore,SG": ("ap-southeast-1", (1.3521, 103.8198)),
    "Sydney,AU": ("ap-southeast-2", (-33.8688, 151.2093)),
    "Tokyo,JP": ("ap-northeast-1", (35.6895, 139.6917)),
    "Frankfurt,DE": ("eu-central-1", (50.1147, 8.6821)),
    "Ireland,IE": ("eu-west-1", (53.4129, -8.2439)),
    "London,UK": ("eu-west-2", (51.5074, -0.1278)),
    "Paris,FR": ("eu-west-3", (48.8566, 2.3522)),
    "Sao Paulo,BR": ("sa-east-1", (-23.5505, -46.6333)),
}


def get_my_long_lat(ip):
    import requests
    import json

    url = "http://ip-api.com/json/" + ip
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    return data["lat"], data["lon"]


def distance_between_two_long_lats(long1, lat1, long2, lat2):
    import math

    R = 6373.0
    dlon = math.radians(long2 - long1)
    dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) ** 2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(
        math.radians(lat2)
    ) * (math.sin(dlon / 2) ** 2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    return R * c


def get_closest_state_long_lat(ip):
    my_long, my_lat = get_my_long_lat(ip)
    min_distance = 10000000000
    closest_state = ""
    for state in aws_regions:
        state_long, state_lat = aws_regions[state][1]
        distance = distance_between_two_long_lats(
            my_long, my_lat, state_long, state_lat
        )
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            closest_state = state
    return closest_state


def get_my_ip():
    import requests
    import json

    url = "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    return data["ip"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = get_my_ip()
    closest_state = get_closest_state_long_lat(ip)
    print(aws_regions[closest_state][0])
```

Note: you can adjust the values to different long lats based on the precision you want. Regions have availability zones, which means that those values might not be accurate all the time. Availability zones can be in different states than the main advertised ones.

Comment: but some times the physical distance is not the accurate as per the latency test, how can i do the latency test by taking my current location.

Comment: this is pretty complicated code. it also won't likely work on a CI server if one is being used.